# Pass a value from controller to view

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a problem in passing a value from controller to view

In controller, In the edit method

```
    public ActionResult Edit( FormCollection form)
        {
        var id = Int32.Parse(form["CustomerServiceMappingID"]);

        var datacontext = new ServicesDataContext();
        var serviceToUpdate = datacontext.Mapings.First(m => m.CustomerServiceMappingID    == id);
        TryUpdateModel(serviceToUpdate, new string[] { "CustomerID", "ServiceID", "Status" }, form.ToValueProvider());

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            try
            {
                var qw = (from m in datacontext.Mapings
                          where id == m.CustomerServiceMappingID
                          select m.CustomerID).First();
                ViewData["CustomerID"] = qw;
                datacontext.SubmitChanges();
                //return Redirect("/Customerservice/Index/qw");
                return RedirectToAction("Index", new { id = qw });
            }
            catch{
                }
        }

        return View(serviceToUpdate);
    }
```

Now in edit's view , I used this

```
                           @Html.Encode(ViewData["CustomerID"])
```

This is my Index method

```
    public ActionResult Index(int id)
    {

        var dc = new ServicesDataContext();
        var query = (from m in dc.Mapings
                   where m.CustomerID == id
                    select m);
       // var a = dc.Customers.First(m => m.CustomerId == id);
       // ViewData.Model = a;
       // return View();
        return View(query);
    }
```

But the customerID on the page turns to be null.. Can u let me know if this procedure is correct?

Comment: can you post the signature of your Index action?

Comment: You're just swallowing your exceptions in the try/catch block that sets the `qw` variable in the first place. Are you sure that `qw` is actually being populated before your View is rendered? Are any exceptions actually being thrown?

Comment: take a good look at your Edit method you set `ViewData["CustomerID"] = qw;` and redirects to `index` and the code path that leads to Edit view does not set `CustomerID`

Comment: I removed try catch blocks.... but still it returns null.

Comment: @Eranga : K ... so what can I do?Can you please help me out

Comment: Is the problem with your Index View or your Edit View?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to requery the id. Just use the id directly:

```
if (ModelState.IsValid)
{
  datacontext.SubmitChanges();
  //return Redirect("/Customerservice/Index/qw");
  return RedirectToAction("Index", new { id = id});
}
```

Since you are redirecting the ViewData["CustomerID"] will be lost.
However the id in your Index method should be valid.
If your Index View requires the ViewData["CustomerID"] set it in your Index action:

```
public ActionResult Index(int id)
{
  ViewData["CustomerID"] = id;
  //....
```

Comment: Hey..Thank you. However, I actually used it in the other Edit field that I've been using.....

Answer (score 0):

I'm a bit confused as to which view does not have access to `ViewData["CustomerId"]`. If it's the Index view, you should set `ViewData["CustomerId"] = id` there.

Comment: oh... The problem is that id is different from qw.. qw is the customerID whereas id is the incremental unique id of thetable